# How to pass an object to a method and then to an other method

Tags: arrays, string, processing

The program I am currently working on should take a string array, mix the contents of the string array (for example word1 word2 word3 / is reordered to word3 word1 word2) and show the output in the terminal. I have tried 4 different `print` variations now but none of them seem to work. Is there a function I'm missing?

```
import java.util.Random;
Random Random = new Random();

void setup(){

  String[] text3={"Word1", "Word2", "Word3", "Word4", "Word5", "Word6"};
  printArray(scramble(text3));
}

void scramble(String[] str) {                 
  for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    int rd0 = Random.nextInt(i+1);
    int rd1 = Random.nextInt(i+1);
    String temp = str[rd0]; 
    str[rd0] = str[rd1]; 
    str[rd1] = temp; 
  }
}
```

Comment: If you're in Processing, why are you adding "only supported in the JVM" java code for things Processing can already do? [random()](https://processing.org/reference/random_.html) already exists.

Comment: But in my case i need to shuffle around some numbers in order to move things inside the array kind of like the Fisher-Yates Shuffle , is that also possible with just random()?

Comment: By the way in your code `text3` is an array of **one** element, good luck to scramble that!

Comment: Did you read the function description by following the link? Because your question suggests you didn't. Also, as @Orace points out, your array is just a single string at the moment. So even if you do what his answer suggests to do, there's nothing to shuffle.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the 'Procssing' tag is not what OP think it is.

Comment: Oh yeah i see now , im pretty new to arrays and have a hard time understanding all of that sorry. String[] text3={"Word1", "Word2", "Word3", "Word4"}; should have assigned 4 spots now doesnt it?

Comment: @Orace given that Processing relies on a `void setup()` (without visibility, because Processing doesn't use Java's visibility syntax) rather than a `public static void main(String[] argv)`, this is almost certainly real Processing code =)

Comment: @Mike, I put the tag back. Didn't hear about processing until today!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`printArray` accepts an array as parameter.

You actually give it the result of `scramble`, which is `void`.

Call `scramble`, **then** call `printArray` by passing it the array you want to print.

So, just pass the array to the first method and then to the second method:

```
scramble(text3);
printArray(text3);
```

Comment: I'm coming from C++ so bear with me. Won't `scramble()` work on a copy of the array, and `printArray()` would still receive the original non-modified array?

Comment: Nope Java class object (array included) are "reference type" and are passed by reference. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15183387/java-arrays-as-reference-types-in-methods